# How to define an interface for React function component with defaultProps without throwing missing type error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I've been searching through many forums and articles and did not find any successful way to define an interface for a function component in React that has required properties which are defined in defaultProps without throwing a "property is missing" Typescript error.

I've tried to set a default value directly in props but it doesn't work either. Is there any way or it's unresolved issue in React and Typescript?

To see this problem in action, I've provided CodeSandbox project.

[image: Edit misty-pine-rtdl8]

```
type ButtonProps = {
  color: "white" | "green";
};

const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({
  // First way to define default value
  color = "green",
  children
}) => <ButtonContainer>{children}</ButtonContainer>;

// Second way to define default value
Button.defaultProps = {
  color: "white"
} as Partial<ButtonProps>;

const ButtonContainer = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  background-color: ${(props: ButtonProps) => props.color};
`;

const App: FunctionComponent = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    {/* Here is an error */}
    <Button>hello world</Button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: @ford04 It's already in the question. The "Edit on CodeSandbox" button

Comment: oh, my ad-blocker did hide that . Consider to paste the code here also, so the question remains valid, if the sandbox gets deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `color` is the only property on the `ButtonProps` type, you can use [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt), which will set the properties of the type as optional:

```
const Button: FunctionComponent<Partial<ButtonProps>> = ({
  // First way to define default value
  color = "green",
  children
}) => <ButtonContainer>{children}</ButtonContainer>;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-shannon-n46fp).

**Edit**:

Following up on your comment, this is what I would recommend. We can remove the `defaultProps`, and use `ButtonProps` to define the typings for `ButtonContainer`. On the `Button` component, you may simply spread the remaining props into the child `ButtonContainer`.

```
type ButtonProps = {
  color: "white" | "green";
  fontSize: string;
};

const Button: FunctionComponent<Partial<ButtonProps>> = ({
  // First way to define default value
  children,
  ...styleProps
}) => <ButtonContainer {...styleProps}>{children}</ButtonContainer>;

const ButtonContainer = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  background-color: ${(props: ButtonProps) => props.color};
  font-size: ${(props: ButtonProps) => props.fontSize};
`;

const App: FunctionComponent = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    <Button color='green'>hello world</Button>
  </div>
);
```

Here is the updated [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-rain-m7qd9).

Comment: Thank you! And what should I do in case there was more properties?

Comment: That really depends! are they optional?

Comment: That's hard to tell. Imagine that you're building a styleguide. Button has for example 15 properties, 12 of them are optional. However you use most of them in `styled-components` and don't want to use non-null assertion operator because you know, they are defined in `defaultProps`

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused now. I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but it definitely allows you to set them as optional, without using the non-null assertion operator. I added an additional property on the props as a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ButtonProps like this

```js
type ButtonProps = {
  color?: "white" | "green";
};
```

Making the color props optional. And then you can initialize it with a default value, just like you are doing.

```js
const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({
  // First way to define default value
  color = "green",
  children
}) => <ButtonContainer>{children}</ButtonContainer>;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this is exactly what I've wanted to avoid. I don't want to use optional properties because then you have to use non-null assertion operator